# webpage in webView fill issue swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, storyboard

I have a webview in view controller with constraints  like this (second controller):

[image]

my problem is that when show page , the webpage doesn't fill whole webpage view and there are (bottom and up) white space like this:

[image]

I set the controller where there is webPageview in this way:

```
class xViewController: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet var webV : UIWebView!
     var url = ""
     var reloadIcon : UIRefreshControl?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.reloadIcon = UIRefreshControl(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-20, y: 20, width: 40, height: 40))




        //self.webV = UIWebView(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y:0, width : UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height : UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 44))
        self.webV.scalesPageToFit = true
        self.webV.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        self.webV.isOpaque = false
        self.webV.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.webV.delegate = self
     }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.webV.isHidden = true
        self.webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: self.url)! as URL) as URLRequest)
    }
    func resfreshWebView(){

        self.webV.isHidden = true
        webV?.reload(); 
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){


    }
    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {


    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

        self.webV.isHidden = false
    }



}
```

P.S I noted that in storyboard there are the two bar ( black and grey) and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to try `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your layout from all the sides like this

[image]

and this

[image]

After setting this layouts web view is displaying in full view, check the screenshot

[image]